# Is there a way to clone elements using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to clone HTML elements using JQuery?

However, I want to be able to assign the cloned elements new attributes "id, name". So if I had a textfield element, I want to clone it **without** its value and **change** its id and name attribute to "exmple2" if it was named "example" previously.

I would appreciate any help on this and any other implementation I can use to add more elements to my html form that already exists on the page.

Thanks all

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Once you have a cloned element you can change it any way you want to

**Updated**: Didn't notice that you wanted to change both name and id.

```
$("#example").clone()
             .attr({"id":"example2", "name":"example2"})
             .html("new content")
             .appendTo("#container");
```

Answer (score 1):

[documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/clone)

I use jQuery over $ so it works with other libraries. Here is an example on an input text field.

```
jQuery('#example').clone().val('').attr('id', 'exmple2').attr('name', 'exmple2').insertAfter('#example');
```

If you want to clone the event handlers as well, you have to use clone(true).

Comment: you can change both id and name inside same `attr()`-call...makes it a bit shorter and nicer (:

Answer (score 1):

Here is sample of creating clone using jquery.

Html code::

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="margin: 10px 10px 10px 0px" id="addNewDiv"> <table style="width: 100%" id="maintable" class="cloneTable">
    <tr><td><input type="text" name="text" id="text"/></td></tr>
  </table></div>
<input type="button" value="Add New Div" onclick="addNewDiv();" style="background-color: #3E8DE1; color: white;" />
```

Javascript code::

```
var count=1;

function addNewDiv(){
    var $clone = $(".cloneTable:first").clone(true);
        $clone.find(':text,:file').each(function() {
            $(this).attr('id',($(this).attr("id")+count));
            $(this).val('');
        });
         $clone.find("a").each(function() {
              $(this).val('').attr('id', function(_, id) {
                return count;
              });
            });
         $clone.find("span").each(function() {
             $(this).attr({
                id: $(this).attr("id") + count
         });
        });


              $clone.attr( 'id', function() { 

                  return this.id + count; })

         .appendTo('#addNewDiv');
    count=count+1;
  }
```

Here is the link of fiddle of same example. [Clone Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3LwMc/11/)