# Is it possible to Clone HTML Elements in jQuery with new ID and Name?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to clone one row of a table, but when I clone, the new element's `name` and `id` will be the same as the element from which it was cloned.

What I need is the cloned elements with a different `name` and `id`.

Comment: answer is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339730/is-there-a-way-to-clone-elements-using-jquery.

Comment: andbeyond linked to all the answer that is needed. Need to do 20 of them? Wrap that answer in an iterator and add the index to the ID or something similar.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I would pass [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop) a map of key/value pairs to update these values after cloning:

```
$("#selector").clone().prop({ id: "newId", name: "newName"});
```

Cloned elements don't exist in the DOM until you add them, so you're not going to have to worry about duplicate `id`s until you do that.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/BbpRA/

*Update*: In the comment you say you have 20 `input`s you need to clone. I would create a function that takes the DOM element and the new id and name. You could even make a small plugin out of it:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.cloneWithProperties = function (properties) {
        return this.clone().prop(properties);
    };
})(jQuery)
```

Usage:

```
$("#selector").cloneWithProperties({ id: "newId", name: "newName" });
```

Comment: but I have almost 20 Input box which i have to clone

Comment: Shouldn't that be `.attr({...})` instead? Neither id nor name are properties. Both are attributes. http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: "attr" (instead of "prop") would be "more correct", but this is definitely the way to go.

Comment: @techfoobar: `id` and `name` are both [HTMLInputElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLInputElement) *properties*. Using `.prop` is correct here.

Comment: @PoonamBhatt: You're going to have to change the properties manually. There's no built-in way to do it with jQuery, unfortunately. You could wrap this functionality in its own function that you call instead of `clone`

Answer (score 6):

You could try something like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="goodbye">
    Goodbye
    <div id="h1" class="hello">Hello</div>
  </div>
</div>

$('#h1').clone().attr('id','h2').appendTo('.container');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like:

```
var x = $("#selector").clone();

x.find('#oldID1').attr({id: "newID1", name: "newName1"});
x.find('#oldID2').attr({id: "newID2", name: "newName2"});
...
```

Once its done, you can append x to wherever you want.

Pls note that the #selector above refers to your table row element.

Answer (score 0):

You can automate your clone with cloneJS.  It's just a beta version: [CloneJS](https://github.com/yagami271/clonejs)