# How can I mirror the contents of one div inside another?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to show the contents of one div into a different div on my screen. The div I want to copy has a set of buttons, and I want to literally mirror the contents, so all the javascript funcitons/listeners will still work.

I've tried:

```
$("#copy").appendTo("#target");

$(#copy).clone().appendTo("#target");
```

Both lines above copy the buttons and classes, but none of the javascript attached to the original buttons work. Has anyone got any ideas of how I can do this?

It may sound an odd thing to be doing but it's necessary for what I want to do.

Comment: "Clone" is a better word, as mirroring implies reversal of orientation. Also, I doubt you meant "literally" literally. :P

Comment: Hint #1: IDs must be unique.

Comment: what does your code to attach JS to the buttons look like? You will need to make sure your events are attached to some container that exists on the page before the cloning happens.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to Clone html elements in jquery with new ID and name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612498/is-it-possible-to-clone-html-elements-in-jquery-with-new-id-and-name)

Comment: also, clone has arguments that you can use: http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Answer (score 4):

I'd try either this:

```
$(#copy).html().clone(true).appendTo("#target");
```

Or this:

```
$(#copy).clone(true).attr.('id', 'some_other_id').appendTo("#target");
```

... to prevent duplicate ID scenarios. Of course, you'll want to check all descendant elements for the same issue.

Then, consider the event handlers:

> Normally, any event handlers bound to the original element are not copied to the clone. The optional withDataAndEvents parameter allows us to change this behavior, and to instead make copies of all of the event handlers as well, bound to the new copy of the element. As of jQuery 1.4, all element data (attached by the .data() method) is also copied to the new copy.

**[Read more on that](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)**

The best approach is probably to use event delegation (via the `on()` method) and class selectors. This way your newly cloned stuff just works.

Comment: Should mention that `withDataAndEvents` is the boolean value passed to the clone method. (ie `$(#copy).clone(true)` )

Answer (score 0):

have you attempted to set withDataAndEvents to true? If you check the documentation on clone it defaults to false;

http://api.jquery.com/clone/

```
withDataAndEvents (default: false)
Type: Boolean
A Boolean indicating whether event handlers should be copied along with the elements. As of jQuery 1.4, element data will be copied as well.
```

perhaps try cloning as so

```
$("#clone").clone(true, true)
```

Also if you are just cloning input this should work.
The dynamic state of certain form elements (e.g., user data typed into textarea and user selections made to a select) is not copied to the cloned elements. When cloning input elements, the dynamic state of the element (e.g., user data typed into text inputs and user selections made to a checkbox) is retained in the cloned elements.