# function to mirror insertAdjacentHTML

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to write a function to mirror the insertAdjacentHTML dom method [Element.insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) and here it is

```
function insertAdjacent(targetElement) {
'use strict';
return {
    insertAfter: function (newElement, targetElement) {
        var parent = targetElement.parentNode;
        if (parent.lastChild === targetElement) {
            parent.appendChild(newElement);
        } else {
            parent.insertBefore(newElement, targetElement.nextSibling);
        }
    },

    insertAtBegin: function (newElement) {
        var fChild = targetElement.firstChild;
        if (!fChild) {
            targetElement.appendChild(newElement);
        } else {
            targetElement.insertBefore(newElement, fChild);
        }
    },

    insertAtEnd: function (newElement) {
        var lChild = targetElement.lastChild;
        if (!lChild) {
            targetElement.appendChild(newElement);
        } else {
            this.insertAfter(newElement, targetElement.lastChild);
        }
    }
};
}
```

The function works fine when you insert two different element nodes at the beginning and the end as shown [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kellyjoe256/ue53zw0a/). But the problem comes when i try to insert the same element node at the beginning and the end as shown [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kellyjoe256/s5sje3pL/). It only inserts the element node at the end and not at both the beginning and end.
What could be causing this issue? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because One `element` can't be insert in two place at the same time, if you want to do it, at each function's first line, add `newElement = newElement.cloneNode(true);` I've altered your 2nd [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s5sje3pL/1/), have a look.

Comment: Thank you @fuyushimoya, i now get where the problem lies

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that you are using the exact same element, which can only be placed in one place...

If you clone it, there shouldn't be a problem.
[**Here's your second fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/s5sje3pL/3/) exactly as you have written it, with an extra [deepCopy function from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13333781/1326147):

```
adjacentInsert.insertAtBegin(deepCopy(span1));
```

Comment: I can promise this @Armfoot, i didn't understand the `deepCopy` function but thanks anyway

Comment: @kellymandem no problem, a deep clone will help with more complex elements than the one you currently have... If you by chance want to cover Arrays, Dates or others, you can use that function without worrying about importing specific stuff for doing that (e.g. jQuery). It basically covers a lot of cases and normally `Object.create` is defined, so [you can ignore the last create function](https://jsfiddle.net/s5sje3pL/5/) :)

Comment: @kellymandem And by the way, if you prefer just using the `cloneNode` like in _fuyushimoya_'s answer, you only need to use it one time (instead of 3) [like this `adjacentInsert.insertAtEnd(span1.cloneNode(true));`](https://jsfiddle.net/s5sje3pL/9/).

Comment: Thank you @Armfoot, that is a neat little trick. By the way i have just read up on the cloneNode method on the [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) and it also copies the attributes too, so how can you prevent elements with ids from being inserted more than once in the DOM.

Comment: @kellymandem for that you would need to change them case by case, meaning: [`var clonedEl = span1.cloneNode(true); clonedEl.id='myNewClonedID';`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650299/how-do-i-change-the-id-of-a-html-element-with-javascript) or using jQuery: [`$("#span1ID").clone().prop('id','myNewClonedID')`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612498/is-it-possible-to-clone-html-elements-in-jquery-with-new-id-and-name)

Comment: Good stuff @Armfoot, i get now