# Jquery - create multiple buttons/elements from template

Tags: jquery

How to do something like this?

```
const $button = $('<button></button>').css({ color: 'red' })
const $good= $button.text('1')
const $bad= $button.text('2')
const $neutral = $button.text('3')
```

And then:

```
const $wrapper = $('<div />').append($good, $bad, $neutral)
```

In the example above there will be only one button inside div, not 3.

Comment: Have you tried adding `.clone()` to the $good, $bad and $neutral. like `$button.clone().text('1')`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen thanks, please answer so i could accept it.

Comment: Duplicate of [Is there a way to clone elements using JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339730/is-there-a-way-to-clone-elements-using-jquery)

Comment: @GuyIncognito yep

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to use the element `$button` as "template" for multiple elements you can use `.clone` to make a new object from that element.

```js
const $button = $('<button></button>').css({ color: 'red' })
const $good= $button.clone().text('1')
const $bad= $button.clone().text('2')
const $neutral = $button.clone().text('3')

const $wrapper = $('<div />').append($good, $bad, $neutral)

$('body').append($wrapper)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```